# Show play icon on link mouseover

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an effect where a play button is shown when the mouse is hovering over an image. A good example of this is the videos down below on http://www.anyclip.com/

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

HTML and CSS can easily position a play image over a thumbnail image. I'm hoping this wasn't your concern; though I've provided some a demonstration below. The Javascript is rather simple as well. Listen for a mouseover event and a mouseout event, and tweak the styles accordingly.

HTML:

```
<div id="video">
    <img src="playbutton.png" id="play">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#video {
 background-color:blue;
  width:300px;
   height:150px; 
    background-image:url("thumbnail.png");
    position:relative;
}
#play {
    position:absolute;
    height:50px;
    top:50px;
    width:50px;
    left:125px;
    display:none;
}
```

Javascript:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("video");
var play = document.getElementById("play");
elem.onmouseover = function() {
        play.style.display = "inline";
};
elem.onmouseout = function() {
        play.style.display = "none";
};
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/thomas4g/6pjF4/6/)

Someday, this will be possible without any Javascript at all. With multiple background images in CSS3, `:hover` on a thumbnail div could tack on a 'play' background image.

Comment: This won't work for me.  I have a bunch of image thumbnails, I can't have a CSS property for every single one.

Comment: @Tory it wouldn't be that hard to change to use class names. But glad you got it figured out.